# Cant assign a plot to an object in R

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I recently opened some code I wrote a month or so ago suddenly when I try to assign an xyplot to a variable, it doesn't work. But I can still see the plot if I don't assign it to a variable.

Example:

```
xyplot() #returns beautiful plot
p1<-xyplot() #returns nothing
p2<-xyplot() #returns nothing
p1+p2 #returns "Error in p1 + p2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator"
```

I'm using R Studio, which I tried updating to solve the problem, but I have the same problem if I just run it in R as well.

Is something wrong with my settings or how I am assigning/naming the objects? It took me a week to write my code to make these really pretty plots and now it doesn't work and I cant figure out why. I tried changing the object names so they don't have numbers, and I've googled the heck out of this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: is `xyplot` a function you defined or a part of base R?

Comment: xyplot is included in the lattice package. I should have said that. Sorry.

Comment: Just type `p1` to "draw" the plot. Or use `(p1<-xyplot())` (note the extra parenthesis). R doesn't typically print results when you do an assign (`<-`). What were you trying to do with `p1+p2`? You can't exactly "add" plots.

Comment: and of course my code has the x and y variables, as well as a data source defined in the ().

Comment: MrFlick, it was printing the plots when I would assign them a month ago. but I don't really care that it is not doing that now. Although adding the parentheses you suggested does make it print the plot after I assign it. And a month ago it was letting me "add" plots. I want a plot with x=0 and y=0 lines below the data points so the way I did this was drawing an empty plot with those lines and then drawing a plot with the data points and then adding them.

Comment: This doesn't seem likely. lattice hasn't change a lot in the last month. Perhaps you had a different package loaded that provided some other functionality. Hard to say without a time machine at this point. But the behavior you are seeing now is what you should have always seen in "vanilla" R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you had loaded `latticeExtra` last time, which adds the option to add several trellis objects as layers. (See `help("+.trellis", package = "latticeExtra")`.)

```
library(lattice)

p1 <- xyplot(1:10 ~ 1:10)
p2 <- bwplot( ~ runif(10, 1, 10))

p1 + p2 # does not work

library(latticeExtra)

p1 + p2 # works now
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Grid plots (including `lattice` and `ggplot2`) work just like regular R objects. (In fact, they are just regular R objects.)

If you enter `x <- 1 + 2` to your console, you don't see the result `3`. But if you then enter `x` or `print(x)` you will see its value, `3`, printed.

The plots work the same way: `p1 <- xyplot(...)` will assign the plot to `p1`, but not print the plot. If you then enter `p1` or `print(p1)`, the plot will print.

If you enter `1 + 2` into the console *without* assigning it, the result `3` will print. Likewise, if you enter `xyplot(...)` into the console *without* assigning it, the plot will print.

---

You can get both assignment and printing at once if you wrap the whole line in parentheses: `(x <- 1 + 2)` will assign `x` and print `3`. Similarly `(p1 <- xyplot(...))` will assign and print the plot.

Comment: Thanks. This is true. And I can get each plot to print individually by putting parentheses around the the object and plotting function. What I still cant get it to do is add the two plots I've created, which is something it used to do a month ago. I tried (p1+p2) and p3=p1+p2 and p3=(p1+p2) and (p3=p1+p2) and they all return that same error message: "Error in p1 + p2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator"

Comment: Adding lattice plots together seems like a very different question than plots not printing. I don't think it's part of standard `lattice`, maybe it's defined in the `latticeExtra` package?

Comment: Ah! THANK YOU! I'm not sure how latticeExtra was uninstalled but it was. I knew there must be a stupid mistake that was causing this. If you submit this as an answer I will accept it as the answer. Otherwise I can just accept the answer this comment is on. Thanks again. I'm a newbie at R and I run into things like this all the time.

Comment: I think the answer as-is is the best answer for the question you asked. The "adding two plots together" bit probably should have been a different question.